# Como abrir nova janela somente se a mesma já não estiver aberta?

Tags: vb.net, wpf

A pergunta correta seria: como Abrir apenas uma instância dessa janela.

a respeito do programa é um **WPF** e a linguagem é **VB.NET**
Atualmente o código a seguir não me serve, porque se o usuário clicar 10 vezes no botão vai se abrir 10 janelas
*levando em conta que Window1 é meu arquivo Window1.xaml*

```
Dim newWindow As New Window1
newWindow.Show()
```

no windows forms seria só colocar window1.show direto sem serimonia, que se o form ja estivesse aberto ele vinha para cima e se o forme estivesse fechado ele reabriria, mas nada de novas janelas, já no **WPF** eu não consigo o mesmo resultado

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439440/check-if-form-is-opened) ajuda ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aproveitando a indicação do colega [Tuxpilgrim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100155/tuxpilgrim), veja se o seguinte código o ajuda:

```
Dim newWindow As Window1

newWindow = Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Window1).FirstOrDefault

If newWindow Is Nothing Then
    newWindow = New Window1
    newWindow.Show()
Else
    newWindow.Select
End If
```